# VSTO Outlook 2007 Addin Startup throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Cannot complete the operation. You are not connected

Tags: c#, com, outlook, vsto, mapi

We are building an Outlook 2007 add-in using VSTO. We have code in the initialization logic of the addin which retrieves the MAPIOBJECT associated with the Application.Session. The code in question is as follows:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var addIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
            var application = addIn.Application;
            var mapiObject = application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // HANDLE ERROR
        }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
                        // ...
    }

    // Other VSTO generated code

}
```

This code works like a charm for most times. However, we run into the following error when we attempt to access the MAPIOBJECT property from the Session property:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x86220009): Cannot complete the operation. You are not connected.
  at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace.get_MAPIOBJECT()
  at MyTestAddIn.ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup(object, System.EventArgs) in C:\foo\MyTestAddIn\ThisAddIn.cs:line 19
```

We are unable to understand why the code works most of the time but fails at a few. We thought this issue was due a network interruption/user working offline. We tried several combinations of connection states with intentionally working offline from Outlook to disconnecting the network cable when Outlook is about to load the add-in. But we have not been able to reproduce the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to ask for the MAPI session that early, because it might not be properly logged on yet. Why not ask for the session the moment you actually *need* it?